# Scrapy Case : Incremental Update of Items

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

Please help me solve following case:

Imagine a typical classified category page. A page with list of items. When you click on items you land on internal pages.Now currently my crawler scrapes all these URLs, further scrapes these urls to get details of the item, check to see if the initial seed URL as any next page. If it has, it goes to the next page and do the same. I am storing these items in a sql database.

Let say 3 days later, there are new itmes in the Seed URL and I want to scrap only new items. Possible solutions are:

1. At the time of scraping each item, I check in the database to see if the URL is already scraped. If it has, I simply ask Scrapy to stop crawling further.
   Problem : I don't want to query database each time. My database is going to be really large and it will eventually make crawling super slow.
2. I try to store last scraped URL and pass it on in the beginning, and the moment it finds this last_scraped_url it simply stops the crawler.
   Not possible, given the asynchronous nature of crawling URLs are not scraped in the same order they are received from seed URLs.
   ( I tried all methods to make it in orderly fashion - but that's not possible at all )

Can anybody suggest any other ideas ? I have been struggling over it for past three days.

Appreciate your replies.

Comment: How are the items in the Seed URL generated?  Do you have any control over this?

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to give you an idea...

I must say I would try first your database option. Databases are made just for that and, even if your DB gets really big, this should not do the crawling significantly slow.
And one lesson I have learned: "First do the dumb implementation. After that, you try to optimize." Most of times when you optimize first, you just optimize the wrong part.

But, if you really want another idea...
Scrapy's default is not to crawl the same url two times. So, before start the crawling you can put the already scraped urls (3 days before) in the list that Scrapy uses to know which urls were already visited. (I don't know how to do that.)
Or, simpler, in your item parser you can just check if the url was already scraped and return None or scrape the new item accordingly.